# env not defined error - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS & julia 0.3 & ODBC 0.3.1

Tags: postgresql, odbc, julia

I'm running into issues trying to use the ODBC package in Julia to connect to Postgre. Code and error below

```
using ODBC

advancedconnect("Driver={psqlODBC};ServerName=xxxx;Username=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Database=xxxx;Port=5432");

env not defined
while loading In[13], in expression starting on line 9 
in advancedconnect at /home/koen.michiels/.julia/v0.3/ODBC/src/userfacing.jl:23
in advancedconnect at /home/koen.michiels/.julia/v0.3/ODBC/src/userfacing.jl:22*
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a look at the source code and it seemed that env is misspelled and therefore I get this error.

Comment: in addition, found out this was already solved in the git in October so I have no idea why this was the case on my machine since i use Julia pkg.add and only started using Julia last week?

Comment: Best to continue discussion over there.